# Can not update the value in class

Tags: ios, swift, class

### This is my class Designed.

```
open class SBCity: NSObject {
    var CM_CityID:String = ""
    var CM_CityName:String = ""
    var CM_OrderBy:Int = 0

    required public init(CM_CityID:String,CM_CityName:String,CM_OrderBy:Int) {
        self.CM_CityID = CM_CityID
        self.CM_CityName = CM_CityName
        self.CM_OrderBy = CM_OrderBy
    }
}
```

### ViewController

In the `ViewController` I have the tableView contain the following three details in each cell. I just append the value in the class on my UITableView `didSelect` method.

```
var source:SBCity?
var destination:SBCity?

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if filterdata.count != 0 {
        return filterdata.count
    } else {
        if tableView == FirstTable {
            return ArrcityList.count
        } else {
            return ArrcityList.count
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if tableView == FirstTable{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecentCityCell") as! RecentCityCell
        cell.cities = ArrcityList[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    //if tableView is not table1 then

    if filterdata.count != 0 {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SourceCityCell")
            as! SourceCityCell
        cell2.cities = filterdata[indexPath.row]
        return cell2
    } else {
        let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SourceCityCell")
            as! SourceCityCell
        cell2.cities = ArrcityList[indexPath.row]
        return cell2
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if isSelectingSource {
        if tableView == FirstTable{
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let crrtCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! RecentCityCell
            self.source = SBCity(CM_CityID: crrtCell.lblID.text!, CM_CityName: crrtCell.lblCity1.text!, CM_OrderBy: 0)
            source = SBCity(CM_CityID: crrtCell.lblID.text!, CM_CityName: crrtCell.lblCity1.text!, CM_OrderBy: 0)
            SourceCityName = crrtCell.lblCity1.text!
            self.moveOnNextVc()
        } else {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let crrtCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! SourceCityCell
            self.source = SBCity(CM_CityID: crrtCell.lblID2.text!, CM_CityName: crrtCell.lblCity2.text!, CM_OrderBy: 0)
            source = SBCity(CM_CityID: crrtCell.lblID2.text!, CM_CityName: crrtCell.lblCity2.text!, CM_OrderBy: 0)
            SourceCityName = crrtCell.lblCity2.text!
            self.moveOnNextVc()
        }
    } else if isSelectingDestination {
        if tableView == FirstTable{
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let crrtCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! RecentCityCell
            self.destination = SBCity(CM_CityID: crrtCell.lblID.text!, CM_CityName: crrtCell.lblCity1.text!, CM_OrderBy: 0)
            destination = SBCity(CM_CityID: crrtCell.lblID.text!, CM_CityName: crrtCell.lblCity1.text!, CM_OrderBy: 0)
            DestinationCityName = crrtCell.lblCity1.text!
            self.moveOnNextVc()
        } else {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            let crrtCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! SourceCityCell
            self.destination = SBCity(CM_CityID: crrtCell.lblID2.text!, CM_CityName: crrtCell.lblCity2.text!, CM_OrderBy: 0)
            destination = SBCity(CM_CityID: crrtCell.lblID2.text!, CM_CityName: crrtCell.lblCity2.text!, CM_OrderBy: 0)
            DestinationCityName = crrtCell.lblCity2.text!
            self.moveOnNextVc()
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not append the value in the class. it's showing nil every time. What's the wrong with the code?

Comment: In didselect else do you want to store source or destination?

Comment: This code... `CM_`, `!`, the indentation... I can't even.

Comment: Actually there is also else part of  `if isSelectingSource` option in which i want to store the Destination.

Comment: Unrelated but why do you assign a city to `source` and `destination` twice respectively? And I agree with Alexander, the upper- and snake-cased variable names are very hard to read.

Comment: Actually the the table is showing city name. I used one table for the source and destination. Are you getting?

Comment: @krunalnagvadia Update the question with numberofSections, numberofrows and cellforrow methods

Comment: updated. please check @RajeshKumarR

Comment: You have been using a lot of redundant statements here. For example, you already have `indexPath` as a parameter to the didSelectRowAt method. Then, you are assigning object twice to the `source` reference, once as `self.source` and again as plain `source`. Correct these first, then move on to the next.

Comment: Ok i remove that still not working. @nayem

Comment: yes. and also change the variable name. still not worked. @vadian

Comment: @krunalnagvadia **_append the value in the class_** Do you want to append a new city in array?